# When do we learn that Sazed shaves his head?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

I have recently started reading *The Well of Ascension*.

Chapter 4 says:

> Sazed still kept his head shaved, after the manner of the station he had served in for the first forty-some years of his life.

The statement felt odd to me since in the first book I always imagined Sazed wearing some kind of haircut.

Looking on the internet and at his fanarts I found confirmation for his baldness, so I read again the entire book in search of the passage that confirms his hairstyle, but I didn't find it. Would anyone be able to point me to the passage where his baldness is first mentioned?

Comment: I've only had a very quick search through the books, but that passage seems to be the first of several mentions of Sazed being bald. "*Sazed’s soldiers backed away. There was little hope left in them. Sazed alone stood in the quiet snow, a spindly, bald scholar...*", and "*There was no way to hide Sazed’s identity. His nationality was obvious. He was too tall, too bald, and he had the typical Terris long face with drooping features and earlobes stretched out by the application of numerous earrings.*", and "*Sazed sewed a rent in his sleeve, oiled his walking boots, and shaved his head.*", etc

Comment: Sazed's entry on the Coppermind wiki (not linked because it contains spoilers for all Mistborn books) cites The Final Empire, Chapter 22 next to "He has a shaven head". However, I couldn't find any mention of his baldness in that chapter in my copy.

Comment: @TheGamer007 - Nor in mine

Comment: Definitely no mention in "Mistborn", re-read it last night specifically looking for any references.  It's clear that Vin can see his ears and the numerous earrings in them, but there's a point where the sweat on his brow is noted.  If he were bald or shaven then something like "sweat stood out on his bald/shaven head" would make more sense, but to only note the brow suggests that the rest of the head is not visible, or he has curiously selective sweat glands.

Comment: I'm wondering if an early edition had any illustrations